# Unity - Autoscroll when selecting buttons out of viewport

Tags: unity

I have a ScrollView element, that contains many buttons. I want that when I select buttons (via arrow keys), the panel scrolls so that the selected button is contained within the viewport.

How could I achieve this?

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is example of my structure (with 2 buttons only, but you get the gist...)

[image]

Comment: Your UI has the black dot optical illusion, not sure if you are aware, very annoying.

Comment: The aesthetics are not final. Im just prototyping the structure of the menu ;) I know it looks hideous now :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to set the value of the ScrollRect's [verticalNormalizedPosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-verticalNormalizedPosition.html) (0f - 1f). Here's the solution I came up with (doesn't include horizontal elements, but similar logic could be applied for your use case).

**ButtonSelectionController (attached to ScrollView)**

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(ScrollRect))]
public class ButtonSelectionController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float               m_lerpTime;
    private ScrollRect          m_scrollRect;
    private Button[]            m_buttons;
    private int                 m_index;
    private float               m_verticalPosition;
    private bool                m_up;
    private bool                m_down;

    public void Start()
    {
        m_scrollRect        = GetComponent<ScrollRect>();
        m_buttons           = GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();
        m_buttons[m_index].Select();
        m_verticalPosition  = 1f - ((float)m_index / (m_buttons.Length - 1));
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        m_up    = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow);
        m_down  = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow);

        if (m_up ^ m_down)
        {
            if (m_up)
                m_index = Mathf.Clamp(m_index - 1, 0, m_buttons.Length - 1);
            else
                m_index = Mathf.Clamp(m_index + 1, 0, m_buttons.Length - 1);

            m_buttons[m_index].Select();
            m_verticalPosition = 1f - ((float)m_index / (m_buttons.Length - 1));
        }

        m_scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition = Mathf.Lerp(m_scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition, m_verticalPosition, Time.deltaTime / m_lerpTime);
    }
}
```

All button children of the ScrollView are got during `Start`, and the initial button is [selected](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.Select.html). During `Update` we're then XOR-ing the up and down arrows so as not to constantly scroll up and down.

I'm then clamping the value of the index to use to the number of button available, before selecting the button at the new index. The position of the ScrollRect is then set to a percentage based on which button is selected from the list (we're subtracting the value from 1f because the position variable works from the bottom up). The new position is then lerped to over the time specified by `m_lerpTime`.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: Excuse me! How does `m_up ^ m_down` work in this case?

Comment: I think `m_up ^ m_down` is intended to prevent any action if both buttons are pressed. I'm not sure why (up would take precedence which doesn't seem crazy).

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed work with the arrow keys but unfortunately it doesn't with a controller and scrolling with the mouse stops working too (using the default `Horizontal` and `Vertical` axis) - both with the mouse wheel and draggin the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use BaseInputModule's movement (which could support gamepad with an [appropriate InputModule](https://github.com/daemon3000/InputManager/blob/master/Assets/InputManager/Addons/UIInputModules/Runtime/StandaloneInputModule.cs)), you'll want to modify `verticalNormalizedPosition` based on the position of your selected object relative to its anchor and mask region. You can see a working example in [UIScrollToSelection.cs](https://bitbucket.org/UnityUIExtensions/unity-ui-extensions/src/2885d851d1ecf034250264d4e9b8cd606239a1a2/Scripts/Utilities/UIScrollToSelection.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

I found it has some bad early out cases for my multiple layer hierarchy ("check if scrolling is possible"), unsmooth upward scrolling, and no scrollwheel handling (IScrollHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler).

If you wanted to do it yourself:

- get the selected element (`EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>()`)
- project its position into your view (`anchoredPosition.y + scrollRect.content.anchoredPosition.y`)
- imagine what's the first and last valid position for your element (0 and mask height less the height of one element)
- then check if your element is before the first valid or after the last valid and add or decrement accordingly.

To avoid fighting with the mouse, you should implement IScrollHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler and disable your autoscroll (I also clear the currentSelectedGameObject).

Comment: There's a two-dimensional variant of the script I linked: [UIScrollToSelectionXY.cs](https://bitbucket.org/UnityUIExtensions/unity-ui-extensions/src/2885d851d1ecf034250264d4e9b8cd606239a1a2/Scripts/Utilities/UIScrollToSelectionXY.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default). I have not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution:

1. get the current selection
2. check if it's a child of the ScrollRect
3. use a [bit of math](https://gist.github.com/sttz/c406aec3ace821738ecd4fa05833d21d) to scroll to it directly:

This works pretty well, and can be limited to only react to controller or keyboard navigation.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
// https://gist.github.com/sttz/c406aec3ace821738ecd4fa05833d21d
namespace UI
{
    public static class UIExtensions {
        // Shared array used to receive result of RectTransform.GetWorldCorners
        static readonly Vector3[] Corners = new Vector3[4];

        /// <summary>
        /// Transform the bounds of the current rect transform to the space of another transform.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The rect to transform</param>
        /// <param name="target">The target space to transform to</param>
        /// <returns>The transformed bounds</returns>
        // ReSharper disable once MemberCanBePrivate.Global
        public static Bounds TransformBoundsTo(this RectTransform source, Transform target)
        {
            // Based on code in ScrollRect internal GetBounds and InternalGetBounds methods
            Bounds bounds = new Bounds();
            if (source != null) {
                source.GetWorldCorners(Corners);

                Vector3 vMin = new Vector3(float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue, float.MaxValue);
                Vector3 vMax = new Vector3(float.MinValue, float.MinValue, float.MinValue);

                Matrix4x4 matrix = target.worldToLocalMatrix;
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    Vector3 v = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(Corners[j]);
                    vMin = Vector3.Min(v, vMin);
                    vMax = Vector3.Max(v, vMax);
                }

                bounds = new Bounds(vMin, Vector3.zero);
                bounds.Encapsulate(vMax);
            }
            return bounds;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Normalize a distance to be used in verticalNormalizedPosition or horizontalNormalizedPosition.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="scrollRect">The target scrollRect</param>
        /// <param name="axis">Scroll axis, 0 = horizontal, 1 = vertical</param>
        /// <param name="distance">The distance in the scroll rect view coordinate space</param>
        /// <returns>The normalized scroll distance</returns>
        // ReSharper disable once MemberCanBePrivate.Global
        public static float NormalizeScrollDistance(this ScrollRect scrollRect, int axis, float distance)
        {
            // Based on code in ScrollRect internal SetNormalizedPosition method
            RectTransform viewport = scrollRect.viewport;
            RectTransform viewRect = viewport != null ? viewport : scrollRect.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            Rect rect = viewRect.rect;
            Bounds viewBounds = new Bounds(rect.center, rect.size);

            RectTransform content = scrollRect.content;
            Bounds contentBounds = content != null ? content.TransformBoundsTo(viewRect) : new Bounds();

            float hiddenLength = contentBounds.size[axis] - viewBounds.size[axis];
            return distance / hiddenLength;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Scroll the target element to the vertical center of the scroll rect viewport.
        /// Assumes the target element is part of the scroll rect contents.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="scrollRect">Scroll rect to scroll</param>
        /// <param name="target">Element of the scroll rect content to center vertically</param>
        public static void ScrollToCenter(this ScrollRect scrollRect, RectTransform target)
        {
            // The scroll rect view space is used to calculate scroll position
            RectTransform view = scrollRect.viewport != null ? scrollRect.viewport : scrollRect.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

            // Calculate the scroll offset in the view's space
            Rect viewRect = view.rect;
            Bounds elementBounds = target.TransformBoundsTo(view);
            float offset = viewRect.center.y - elementBounds.center.y;

            // Normalize and apply the calculated offset
            float scrollPos = scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition - scrollRect.NormalizeScrollDistance(1, offset);
            scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition = Mathf.Clamp(scrollPos, 0f, 1f);
        }
    }
}


using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace UI
{
  [RequireComponent(typeof(ScrollRect))]
  public class ScrollRectAutoScroll : MonoBehaviour
  {
    [Tooltip("The UI/Navigate action used by controller and keyboard to use menus")]
    [SerializeField] InputActionReference navigateAction;
    /// <summary>
    /// The scrollRect attached to this component
    /// </summary>
    ScrollRect _scrollRect;

    public void Start()
    {
      // Get the scrollRect
      _scrollRect = GetComponent<ScrollRect>();
      // Scroll to selection on init
      ScrollToSelection();
    }

    void ScrollToSelection()
    {
      // Get the selection
      GameObject selection = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject;
      // If no selection, return
      if (!selection) return;
      // If selection is not a child of the scrollRect, return
      if (!selection.transform.IsChildOf(transform)) return;
      // If somehow the selection is not a RectTransform, return
      if (!selection.TryGetComponent(out RectTransform rectTransform)) return;
      // Scroll into view
      _scrollRect.ScrollToCenter(rectTransform);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
      // If user has used the navigate buttons this frame, update scroll
      if (navigateAction.action.inProgress)
        ScrollToSelection();
    }
  }
}
```